# "|=" operator in JS (never seen before)

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

I just encountered the code below.

```
var loadComplete = 0;
window.onload = function(){
    loadComplete |= 1;
};
```

I've never seen "|=" like operator.
Also I have googled about it, but there seems to be no example of it.

Comment: same as `loadComplete =  loadComplete | 1;` where `|` is the [bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) OR

Comment: Do you know what `+=` does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as `x += 1` is equivalent to `x = x + 1`, `x |= 1` is the same as `x = x | 1`, [**where `|` is the bitwise OR operator.**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/81bads72%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Bitwise OR:

```
var a = 205;   // In binary: 11001101
var b = 45;    // In binary: 00101101
var c = a | b; // In binary: 11101101
```

Basically, if there are **any** ones in the column, it keeps it, and converts back to decimal notation, `237`.

Comment: It's an or not xor. Xor is ^